# Chips component in android support library?

Tags: android, material-design, android-chips

[This](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/chips.html#chips-usage) material design show case says about chips component. But I couldn't find example code of this component?

How can I use it?

please show me XML code and java code.

Comment: see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22243669/6561141). It's actually from google!

Comment: Check out my answer for an approach without 3rd party library.

Comment: Just use the official [Material Components Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28045091/android-material-chips/50155934#50155934)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You do not need to use a 3rd party library to make [chips](https://material.io/guidelines/components/chips.html).

A chip is basically a `TextView` with a rounded background. You can add a delete button and an `ImageView` also to create a view such as the one used for Google contacts.

For the purposes of the example I will only use a simple `TextView`. First create the UI for the chip.

-> ***shape_chip_drawable.xml***

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="12dp"
        android:left="12dp"
        android:right="12dp"
        android:top="12dp" />

    <corners android:radius="30dp" />
</shape>
```

In your activity layout file, just define this drawable resource file as the `TextView` background like this:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@drawable/shape_chip_drawable"
    android:text="Hello, I'm a simple Chip!"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

This is the view which is created:

[image: Chip view created]

Now we can use `HorizontalScrollView` to display a row of chips (like GooglePlay application) or use `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` to build a staggered grid of chips.

[EDIT]

If you want to show the chips as a `FlowLayout`, which is not inherently supported in Android, we need to use a Library. Don't worry, its a very small change.

You have add the following line to your Gradle depencencies:

```
compile 'com.xiaofeng.android:flowlayoutmanager:1.2.3.2'
```

and set your recycler view layout manager with it:

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new FlowLayoutManager());
```

Additional details here on [GitHub](https://github.com/xiaofeng-han/AndroidLibs/tree/master/flowlayoutmanager)

Have a great day! Do upvote if it helps.

Comment: Thanks. Using recycler with the flowLayoutManager is muuuuch better then any other solution

Comment: Nice, easy, and light ! Best solution, we can also easily put a right drawable to make a removable chip !!

Comment: Great Solution!   How can i change from code the "color" ¿?

Comment: What about the small circular image?

Answer (score 4):

Try this library:
https://github.com/klinker41/android-chips

Check the sample to get the feel for how to use it.

Comment: It looks like 3rd party library which is not made by google.
where is original chips library from Android material design.

Comment: It's based on the Google's source for AOSP messenger. If it works use it. Material specs are only specs, it's not guaranteed that Google will prepare first party solution for every component.

Comment: see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22243669/6561141). It's actually from google!

Comment: Check out my answer for an approach without 3rd party library.

Comment: There is an official `Chip` implementation but it's in alpha atm (see https://material.io/components/android/catalog/chip/ and https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html), it'll be released in version 28.0.0 of the design support library.

Comment: **AndroidX** https://github.com/karanatwal/MaterialChipsInput

Answer (score 4):

I know i'm late but this can help other people. I really like this implementation also https://github.com/robertlevonyan/materialChipView. This lib requires atleast `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0` of the support library. I use it with this layout manager https://github.com/BelooS/ChipsLayoutManager.
Check these out and see if they meet your requirements.

Comment: It'd be great if it was written properly. Unfortunately it has numerous problems - especially if you are using it programmatically.  Such a disappointment.

Comment: Tried the library. Yes it has a lot of problems. Wasted my time

Comment: For **AndroidX** https://github.com/karanatwal/MaterialChipsInput