# How to implement Android material chips for contacts selection without a third party library?

Tags: android-chips

[image]

How can I implement Android Material Design chips without an external library. Google Apps have it inside their apps, so I guess that it should be available in the native SDK. If yes, how to implement it for a contacts selection functionality. Similar to the given screenshot.

Comment: any luck with it?

Comment: @rookieDeveloper not yet! But basically, the concept goes around concatenating strings by a StrinbBuilder and then assign these strings to a textview. Give some style to the textview like padding, round corners,etc.

Comment: Check out this answer. Should help. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41776777/2254969

Comment: See My Answer and code sample https://stackoverflow.com/a/52007466/5439116

Answer (score 0):

Google has officially released a library for it you can use that:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
}
```

Then you just need to add it in XML, like this :

```
<chip
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Entry"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:checkable="false"
app:chipIcon="@drawable/ic_android_24dp"
app:iconStartPadding="5dp"/>
```

Or you can add it dynamically as stated here:
[Stack Overflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51610997/905858)

Taken from [Chips Example here](https://www.truiton.com/2018/10/android-chips-example-material-design/). More info about chips is also stated here.