# How to add chips from Material Components library to input field in android?

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android, material-components, android-chips

I've seen that in android-P google add new material components library which contains material chips:

[Material components for android](https://material.io/develop/android/components/chip/)

[Material.io chips usage](https://material.io/design/components/chips.html#usage)

[Material components on GitHub](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android)

So I decided to add material input chips to my project, but unfortunately didn't find any tutorial how to make that. I want to create something like Gmail chips but without image on the start.

Because I'm using appcompat library I tried to use material chips by `android.support.design.chip.Chip` and `android.support.design.chip.ChipGroup`.
But result was just chips without any input field. Also I tried to create a Standalone ChipDrawable and then add it to `EditText` using

```
Editable text = editText.getText();

text.setSpan(span, 0, text.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

But I got empty EditText without any chips. So how can I create chips input like in Gmail using this material components library? Maybe someone has expreience or knows any tutorials where I could see how to create this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please check my answer and code sample : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52007466/5439116

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**Answer**

No default input field for adding chips in android. They mentioned input chips but i didn't find any layout or viewgroup for input chips.  So i do with `Chipdrawable` method to add chips in edittext. Here am using [AppCompatEdittext](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatEditText) you can change to anyview which listening the text inputs.
[Reference](https://material.io/develop/android/components/chip/).

**Step 1**

Add chip xml resource. **chip.xml**

> res -> xml -> chip.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<chip xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:textAppearance="@style/ChipTextAppearance"
 app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/colorAccent"
 app:chipIcon="@drawable/ic_call_white_24dp"
 app:closeIconEnabled="true"  <!--property for close icon if no need set to false. -->
 app:closeIconTint="@android:color/white" />
```

Then add textappearance style in style.xml(For change textStyle)

```
<style name="ChipTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Chip">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

**Step 2**

Add your view here am using AppCompatEdittext

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
    android:id="@+id/phone"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvt_Contact" />
```

**Step 3**
Add this code to your view to get the desired behaviour.

```
 private int SpannedLength = 0,chipLength = 4;

 AppCompatEditText Phone = findViewById(R.id.phone);

 Phone.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            if (charSequence.length() == SpannedLength - chipLength)
            {
                SpannedLength = charSequence.length();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            if(editable.length() - SpannedLength == chipLength) {
                ChipDrawable chip = ChipDrawable.createFromResource(getContext(), R.xml.chip);
                chip.setChipText(editable.subSequence(SpannedLength,editable.length()));
                chip.setBounds(0, 0, chip.getIntrinsicWidth(), chip.getIntrinsicHeight());
                ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(chip);
                editable.setSpan(span, SpannedLength, editable.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                SpannedLength = editable.length();
            }

        }
    });
```

**Change chipLength according to your need when new chip need to be added in edittext.**

**OUTPUT**

[image]

**EDITED**

You can find more about how to align center the text with span [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25628258/align-text-around-imagespan-center-vertical).

Here i added some code from the solution will fix for you..

```
public class VerticalImageSpan extends ImageSpan {

public VerticalImageSpan(Drawable drawable) {
    super(drawable);
}

@Override
public int getSize(@NonNull Paint paint, CharSequence text, int start, int end,
                   Paint.FontMetricsInt fontMetricsInt) {
    Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
    Rect rect = drawable.getBounds();
    if (fontMetricsInt != null) {
        Paint.FontMetricsInt fmPaint = paint.getFontMetricsInt();
        int fontHeight = fmPaint.descent - fmPaint.ascent;
        int drHeight = rect.bottom - rect.top;
        int centerY = fmPaint.ascent + fontHeight / 2;

        fontMetricsInt.ascent = centerY - drHeight / 2;
        fontMetricsInt.top = fontMetricsInt.ascent;
        fontMetricsInt.bottom = centerY + drHeight / 2;
        fontMetricsInt.descent = fontMetricsInt.bottom;
    }
    return rect.right;
}

@Override
public void draw(@NonNull Canvas canvas, CharSequence text, int start, int end,
                 float x, int top, int y, int bottom, @NonNull Paint paint) {

    Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
    canvas.save();
    Paint.FontMetricsInt fmPaint = paint.getFontMetricsInt();
    int fontHeight = fmPaint.descent - fmPaint.ascent;
    int centerY = y + fmPaint.descent - fontHeight / 2;
    int transY = centerY - (drawable.getBounds().bottom - drawable.getBounds().top) / 2;
    canvas.translate(x, transY);
    drawable.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}

}
```

And change your imagespan class like below

```
VerticalImageSpan span = new VerticalImageSpan(chip);
```

Comment: how to make input text `center vertical` ? so that text inside chip and outside would be on the same level

Comment: @SviatVolkov You need to add custom class in order to get text see my edited answer.

Comment: how can I add chip as background ,if I select contact from contact list using filter.

Comment: I'm having `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).` during the `ChipDrawable` instantation of my instrumented test. Any clue about that? Parent of my App theme is `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge`

Comment: close icon is not working.

Comment: how to get values back at time of submit ?

Comment: @MohamedMohaideenAH any response to close icon not working and to get the chip values at submit?

Answer (score 27):

All of the previous solutions didn't work for me if you want to achieve a gmail like behaviour with chips on multiple lines. 
In order to do that I had to avoid using the ChipGroup and instead using a **FlexboxLayout**.

[image]

**your_recipient_layout:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/recipient_label_TV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
        android:id="@+id/recipient_group_FL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        app:flexWrap="wrap"
        app:alignItems="stretch"
        app:alignContent="space_around"
        app:showDivider="beginning|middle|end"
        app:dividerDrawable="@drawable/divider">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/recipient_input_ET"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            app:layout_flexGrow="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="text"/>

    </com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recipients_list_RV"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

The trick now is adding a new chip to the group but as second last position. Something like this:

```
private fun addNewChip(person: String, chipGroup: FlexboxLayout) {
    val chip = Chip(context)
    chip.text = person
    chip.chipIcon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(requireContext(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
    chip.isCloseIconEnabled = true
    chip.isClickable = true
    chip.isCheckable = false
    chipGroup.addView(chip as View, chipGroup.childCount - 1)
    chip.setOnCloseIconClickListener { chipGroup.removeView(chip as View) }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked perfectly, I still need to check on Android versions < 23, but this is the best implementation I have found.

Comment: Great idea! You don't need use the chip view, inflate your own layout and add inside FlexboxLayout, my opinion the Chip is only useful, when you are using material component full. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Good idea, i just have to keep edittext background as transparent and draw a line after linear layout to fake the guide line from edittext.  tks

Comment: Good idea, is it possible share full code?

Comment: If customization to the chip is needed, can inflate like this `val chip = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.my_chip_layout, chipGroup, false) as Chip` where the my_chip_layout can have a `<com.google.android.material.chip.Chip` as parent

Comment: How did you get the horizontal margin between chips?

Comment: this is the best approach. Flexbox helps so much here

Answer (score 6):

## Using TextInputLayout

chip_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.chip.Chip xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Action"
    app:closeIconEnabled="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
```

tags_input_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/i_input_v"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:hint="Tags">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:paddingBottom="22dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
        android:id="@+id/i_flex_box"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:alignContent="space_around"
        app:alignItems="stretch"
        app:flexWrap="wrap"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:showDivider="beginning|middle|end">


    </com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

TagInputView.kt

```
class TagInputView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null
) : ConstraintLayout(context, attrs) {

    val chipGroup: ChipGroup

    init {
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tags_input_layout, this, true)

        val inputLayout = findViewById<TextInputLayout>(R.id.i_input_v)
        val editText = inputLayout.editText!!
        chipGroup = findViewById(R.id.i_flex_box)

        editText.onFocusChangeListener = OnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
            if (hasFocus) {
                if (editText.text.toString() == " "){
                    editText.text.clear()
                }
            } else {
                if (editText.text.isNullOrEmpty() && chipGroup.childCount > 0) {
                    editText.setText(" ")
                }
            }
        }

        editText.setOnKeyListener { _, _, event ->
            if (event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
//                onBackspacePressed, also edittext is empty
                if (chipGroup.childCount <= 0) return@setOnKeyListener false
                val lastChip = chipGroup.getChildAt(chipGroup.childCount - 1) as Chip
                editText.append(lastChip.text)
                chipGroup.removeView(lastChip)
            }
            false
        }

        editText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {}
            override fun onTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {}

            override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable) {
                val text = editable.toString()
                if (text.isNotEmpty() && text.endsWith(",")) {
                    addNewChip(text.removeSuffix(","))
                    editable.clear()
                }
            }
        })
    }

    private fun addNewChip(text: String) {
        val newChip =
            LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.chip_item, chipGroup, false) as Chip
        newChip.id = ViewCompat.generateViewId()
        newChip.text = text
        newChip.setOnCloseIconClickListener {
            chipGroup.removeView(newChip)
        }
        chipGroup.addView(newChip)
    }
}
```

### Usage

activity_main.xml

```
...
<com.shubhamgupta16.yourappid.utils.TagInputView
    android:id="@+id/tagInputView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
...
```

You can also access all `Chip` inside `ChipGroup` by using `tagInputView.chipGroup` property.

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 4):

We can do this by using material chips design itself without adding any extra styles.

Add it on app gradle For AndroidX

> implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01'

For earlier than AndroidX use this

> implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

[image]

**Fragment**

```
class EntryChipDemoFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var mView: View

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_entry_chip_demo, container, false)

        mView.etValue.setOnEditorActionListener(TextView.OnEditorActionListener { v, actionId, _ ->
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                val txtVal = v.text
                if(!txtVal.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                    addChipToGroup(txtVal.toString(), mView.chipGroup2)
                    mView.etValue.setText("")
                }

                return@OnEditorActionListener true
            }
            false
        })

        return mView
    }


    private fun addChipToGroup(txt: String, chipGroup: ChipGroup) {
        val chip = Chip(context)
        chip.text = txt
//        chip.chipIcon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(requireContext(), baseline_person_black_18)
        chip.isCloseIconEnabled = true
        chip.setChipIconTintResource(R.color.chipIconTint)

        // necessary to get single selection working
        chip.isClickable = false
        chip.isCheckable = false
        chipGroup.addView(chip as View)
        chip.setOnCloseIconClickListener { chipGroup.removeView(chip as View) }
        printChipsValue(chipGroup)
    }

    private fun printChipsValue(chipGroup: ChipGroup) {
        for (i in 0 until chipGroup.childCount) {
            val chipObj = chipGroup.getChildAt(i) as Chip
            Log.d("Chips text :: " , chipObj.text.toString())

        }
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance() = EntryChipDemoFragment()
    }
}
```

**XML File:**

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/chipGroup2HorizontalView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.62">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Skills: " />

        <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
            android:id="@+id/chipGroup2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:duplicateParentState="false">

        </com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="43dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:minWidth="32dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/chipGroup2HorizontalView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_min="32dp">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:id="@+id/etValue"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</HorizontalScrollView>
```

For more reference [Click Here](https://material.io/develop/android/components/chip/)

Comment: For **AndroidX** with autocomplete functionality https://github.com/karanatwal/MaterialChipsInput

Comment: Hi Naveen, this solution is great. I have one question, is there any way where we can pass a list of strings in ChipGroup, and it will inflate automatically like recycler view?

Comment: @NileshRathore by uisng addChipToGroup function itself you can inflate. Just you want this by programatically instead of typing. So pass the list to this function and iterate it in each loop add view to chipGroup.
Here chipGroup is a just empty container

Comment: Ya, I'm already doing this right now, but problem is that if I get a newly updated list from somewhere, then I have to remove all previously added views and iterate again for adding it one by one. In the recycler view, we have Diff Util so only changed items get updated.

Comment: Yes that is the only way. Or else you can directly use recycler view with ChipGroup in list_row

Answer (score 0):

You can use material chip "com.google.android.material.chip.Chip" and "implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' " add in build.gradle

Filter 
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Filter"

Choice Chips
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice"

Entry input:
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Entry"

Answer (score 0):

[image]

#### Usage

```
chipGroupView.attachTo(tagsInputEditText){ selection ->
   // do something
}
```

#### Code

```
fun ChipGroup.attachTo(editText: EditText, chipChangedCallback: (List<String>) -> Unit) {
    editText.apply {
        onFocusChangeListener = View.OnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
            if (hasFocus) {
                if (text.toString() == " ") {
                    text.clear()
                }
            } else {
                if (text.isNullOrEmpty() && childCount > 0) {
                    setText(" ")
                }
            }
        }

        fun getSelection(): List<String> = mutableListOf<String>().apply {
            for(view in children){
                add(view.findViewById<Chip>(R.id.chipItem).text.toString())
            }
        }

        fun checkHashtag(hashtagInput: String) {
            if(Pattern.matches(Constants.TWITTER_HASHTAG_REGEX, hashtagInput)){
                addTag(hashtagInput){
                    chipChangedCallback(getSelection())
                }
                text.clear()
                chipChangedCallback(getSelection())
            }else{
                VibrateUtils.vibrate(200)
            }
        }

        setOnKeyListener { _, actionId, event ->
            if (event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && event.keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
                if (text.isNotEmpty() || childCount <= 0) return@setOnKeyListener false
                val lastChip = getChildAt(childCount - 1) as LinearLayout
                editText.append(lastChip.findViewById<Chip>(R.id.chipItem).text)
                removeView(lastChip)
                chipChangedCallback(getSelection())
            }
            else if(
                actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH
                || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
                || event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                && event.keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){
                checkHashtag(text.toString())
                return@setOnKeyListener true
            }
            actionId == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER
        }

        addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {}
            override fun onTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {}

            override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable) {
                val text = editable.toString()
                val length = text.length

                if(text == " "){
                    editable.delete(length - 1, length)
                    return
                }
                if (text.isNotEmpty() && text.endsWith(" ")) {
                    val hashtagInput = text.removeSuffix(" ")
                    checkHashtag(hashtagInput)
                }
            }

        })

    }
}

private fun ChipGroup.addTag(tag: String,onRemoved: (View)-> Unit = {}) {
    addView(ChipBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context)).also { itemUi ->
        itemUi.root.findViewById<Chip>(R.id.chipItem).apply {
            text = tag
            setOnClickListener {
                this@addTag.removeView(itemUi.root);
                onRemoved(this)
            }
        }
    }.root)
}
```

chip.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        android:id="@+id/chipItem"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:chipIconSize="16dp"
        app:iconStartPadding="6dp"
        tools:text="Non-Fiction"
        app:chipIcon="@drawable/ic_hash"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Action"
        app:closeIconEnabled="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Note: chipGroupView and tagsInputEditText are vertically wrapped in LinearLayout with a stroked background

Answer (score -1):

Not the ideal solution, but definitely easy

```
<FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:chipMinTouchTargetSize="0dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="10">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/add_frag_label_et_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_weight="9"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:hint="Enter Label"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:paddingStart="8dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="0dp"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/add_frag_label_iv_add"
                    android:layout_width="32dp"
                    android:layout_height="32dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    app:tint="#6b6a6c"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:contentDescription="Add Label to note."
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_plus_foreground" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I am using Chip layout as a background. That's it. On top of that there is a normal edit text and a plus image. You can put on click listener on it to trigger events. It's a quick fix, not a solution.