# How to add chip to edit text in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, android-chips, xml-layout

I found a dependency that I thought might help me, and it looked promising. But when I try to implement it I get a
`"Failed to resolve: com.hootsuite.android:nachos:1.1.1" :`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgbEx.png

And the thing I'm trying to accomplish is this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2JaU.png

as seen in this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UCZeHeDDBMw&list=PLi_3BTX1-5i4ieQOm-W-i3rkOU3qOA06o&index=3&t=401s&ab_channel=AndroidRion

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code and errors as **text** rather than as screenshot(s). On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle's failing to resolve that dependency for some reason. First thing you should check is if there's a site for that library, or an entry in the repositories you're using, to check if that's a valid version or if there's anything else you need to know.

Turns out [it has a project repository on Github](https://github.com/hootsuite/nachos), so there's a readme telling you how to install it:

> Add this line to your project level build.gradle:
>
> ```
> buildscript {
>  repositories {
>    jcenter()
>  }
> ```
>
> Add this line to your module level build.gradle:
>
> ```
> dependencies {
>    implementation "com.hootsuite.android:nachos:1.1.1"
> }
> ```

**But** in this case that won't help - JCenter shut down last year. The last update to this project was 4 years ago - but they have a [JitPack link](https://jitpack.io/#mgbckr/nachos-v2) at the top of the readme. JitPack is basically a way to add dependencies from Github repositories, when they're not in a central repository like the Google one, or Maven Central. So try adding the config stuff at that JitPack link if you want to use this library (you could also build it locally if you really wanted)

---

That said, `Chip`s are part of the *Material Components* library now, so [you might want to just use that instead](https://material.io/components/chips/android) - it's basically part of a typical Android app at this point. Scroll down to the *Standalone `ChipDrawable`* section to see how you can add one to a `TextView`

Comment: I'm trying to use it but for some reason it just doesn't show up in my XML when i try to add it and I added it as the website said. Do you have time to test this?

Comment: @FarisRizvanović not really - if you mean that old library you're trying to use, I'd honestly just use the Material Components one since it's up-to-date and supported, and works with the standard widgets. An old library just might not work anymore. If you *are* talking about the Material library, make sure `google()` is added to you project-level `build.gradle`'s `repositories` section, and add `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'`  to the `dependencies` section of your module-level's `build.gradle` file

Comment: See here for the instructions: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md

Comment: I ended up using the Material Components library Chips, thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this answer. It shows you all the details to set chips in edit text.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50574943/how-to-add-chips-from-material-components-library-to-input-field-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `AppCompatEdittext` you can change to any view which listening the text inputs.

##### Step 1

Create file named  `chip.xml` and Add resource in the following folder.

- res -> xml -> chip.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<chip xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:textAppearance="@style/ChipTextAppearance"
 app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/colorAccent"
 app:chipIcon="@drawable/ic_call_white_24dp"
 app:closeIconEnabled="true"  <!--property for close icon if no need set to false. -->
 app:closeIconTint="@android:color/white" />
```

Then add style in `style.xml`

```
<style name="ChipTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Chip">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

##### Step 2

Add AppCompactEditText

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
    android:id="@+id/phone"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvt_Contact" />
```

##### Step 3

java code

```
private int SpannedLength = 0,chipLength = 4;

 AppCompatEditText Phone = findViewById(R.id.phone);

 Phone.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            if (charSequence.length() == SpannedLength - chipLength)
            {
                SpannedLength = charSequence.length();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            if(editable.length() - SpannedLength == chipLength) {
                ChipDrawable chip = ChipDrawable.createFromResource(getContext(), R.xml.chip);
                chip.setChipText(editable.subSequence(SpannedLength,editable.length()));
                chip.setBounds(0, 0, chip.getIntrinsicWidth(), chip.getIntrinsicHeight());
                ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(chip);
                editable.setSpan(span, SpannedLength, editable.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                SpannedLength = editable.length();
            }

        }
    });
```

```
@Override
public int getSize(@NonNull Paint paint, CharSequence text, int start, int end,
                   Paint.FontMetricsInt fontMetricsInt) {
    Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
    Rect rect = drawable.getBounds();
    if (fontMetricsInt != null) {
        Paint.FontMetricsInt fmPaint = paint.getFontMetricsInt();
        int fontHeight = fmPaint.descent - fmPaint.ascent;
        int drHeight = rect.bottom - rect.top;
        int centerY = fmPaint.ascent + fontHeight / 2;

        fontMetricsInt.ascent = centerY - drHeight / 2;
        fontMetricsInt.top = fontMetricsInt.ascent;
        fontMetricsInt.bottom = centerY + drHeight / 2;
        fontMetricsInt.descent = fontMetricsInt.bottom;
    }
    return rect.right;
}

@Override
public void draw(@NonNull Canvas canvas, CharSequence text, int start, int end,
                 float x, int top, int y, int bottom, @NonNull Paint paint) {

    Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
    canvas.save();
    Paint.FontMetricsInt fmPaint = paint.getFontMetricsInt();
    int fontHeight = fmPaint.descent - fmPaint.ascent;
    int centerY = y + fmPaint.descent - fontHeight / 2;
    int transY = centerY - (drawable.getBounds().bottom - drawable.getBounds().top) / 2;
    canvas.translate(x, transY);
    drawable.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}

}
```

And change your image span class like below

```
VerticalImageSpan span = new VerticalImageSpan(chip);
```

Comment: This is a great answer, but I don't know where to start with this one